# Passport Authentication works through Postman but not Web App

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, passport.js, axios

Using Express and Passport JS on the backend we are currently able to login to the application, and access all of the API requests using postman.

However when we try and make API requests that require authentication on the React JS Web Application we get a 401 unauthorised error.

We've run logs from both the postman request and the web app request and both are passing the connect.sid cookie in the header.

My question is, how do I get the application authenticated and able to make API requests like postman can. I login to postman the same way I do using the web application but it doesn't authenticate the api requests.

Things I've tried:

- manually setting the headers to allow cross origin requests
- setting an Authorize bearer token
- Specifying on the backend the origin of the front end, which only allows api calls to be made from the front end web server

The application is a ReactJS application, and I am making the API calls using Axios

Comment: Can you add code snippet or put it on codesandbox.io?

Comment: @varit05 currently the API request is being made like this: 
       `Axios.get(BASE_URL + API_CALL, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'accept': '/',
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 
            },
        withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.request);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response);
        })`

Comment: with this info, I don't think I can able to help you. There can be an issue with URL set up probably.

Comment: The weird thing is, is that it works through postman, with the exact same URL set up. I think it might be a CORS issue however whenever I try and bypass CORS nothing seems to work

Comment: have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52093083/1042409) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by passing withCredentials on login, this sends your user to the passport.js and authenticates the user.

You need to call withCredentials every time you make an API call though