# Calling local dotnet https backend from local NextJS results in FetchError: self-signed certificate

Tags: .net-core, next.js, ssl-certificate, localhost

I've recently had to switch my local dotnet core 6 backend development to now run on HTTPS due to some Secure cookies being passed between the backend and the front-end. Unfortunately now I'm having some issues when calling it from my NextJS API which is as follows

> error - FetchError: request to https://localhost:5001/api/user/login
> failed, reason: self-signed certificate

My guess would be that it's because I'm not using https for the next.js local server but I don't fully understand why or how to go about that. Any help either with the solution or understanding the problem would be appreciated. Please find below the problematic code block from my NextJS API.

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { User } from '../../models/User';

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<User>
) {
  console.log(req.body);
  await fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/user/login', {
    body: req.body,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response: User) => {
      res.status(200)
        .json(response);
      console.log('res', response);
    });
}
```

Comment: Followed this link to try get it to work. Was really hopeful and it ran it on https but still no luck so maybe it's something else than I thought. https://anmagpie.medium.com/secure-your-local-development-server-with-https-next-js-81ac6b8b3d68

Comment: Maybe you should try consulting with Microsoft about this, specifically the branch that handles .NET

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your certificate with Root CA. Then add it to trusted root certificate.

[image: I used Self sign Laragon]

but you can generate new one following the step

1. create RootCA.pem and RootCA.key
2. create .csr file
3. issue it with RootCA
4. add it to trust root certificate

also you need to config req file and domain.ext

```
sudo openssl req -new -nodes -days 720 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/$Domain.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/$Domain.csr -config /certs/openssl.cnf
       
sudo openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 720 -in /etc/ssl/certs/$Domain.csr -CA /certs/RootCA.pem -CAkey /certs/RootCA.key -CAcreateserial -extfile /certs/domains.ext -out /etc/ssl/certs/$Domain.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0 in the env file. But this should only be for local development. Thank You!
referred solution: ['Error: self signed certificate' with node+express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091435/error-self-signed-certificate-with-nodeexpress-application)